# difference between com.sun.jna and net.java.dev.jna?

Tags: java, jna, maven-central

I'm looking through the central maven repository and seeing a `net.java.dev.jna` and a `com.sun.jna` groupId for JNA. The github for JNA, using the `com.sun.jna` path as the directories in their source code, indicates that 4.1 has been pushed into the repository as part of a comment, but I'm seeing `net.java.dev.jna` at 4.1 and `com.sun.jna` at 3.0.

Obviously, I want to use JNA, but am baffled. What's going on with this package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct 4.1 version to use is `net.java.dev.jna`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The package name still seems to be `com.sun.jna`, but if you look [in the POM file](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/pom-jna.xml), the Maven coordinates have become `net.java.dev.jna:jna`.

They seem to have been that way for quite a long time, based on the [MVN respository results](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna).